# How can i send birthday wishes notifciations to user automatically when the day comes using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications, broadcasting

In my flutter app i am collecting the date of birth of user , now i want to send them birthday wishes as push notifications when the day comes , the notifications should be sent even when the user doesnt uses the app , like facebook ,gmail sends.

Someone suggested me of using **broadcast** for this , but as a beginner in flutter i cannot find a way about how to use it , or can someone please suggest another solution for it.

I used **flutter_local_notifications** as i implemented it in one of my pages it can only be triggered when user runs the app , whereas i want wishes to be sent automatically.
It will be very helpful if someone helped me out here.

Comment: You can schedule a local notification for the particular date as soon as the user submits his/her date of birth.

Comment: Consider i have birthday on 13/04/2000 so what am i supposed to pass to **var schedulednotificationDateTime**  , to schedule it.

Comment: In which format are you getting the date which user enters?

Answer (score 0):

Integrate firebase and there is a too Firebae cloud messaging or you can have your own site and implement it. However, cloud messaging is free.

Answer (score 0):

You can take two ways: You do it from remote on your server than you send a notification (For istance by using Firebase) or you schedule a notification with [flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications).

I'll post you an example by using flutter_local_notification:

Let's say your user inputs something like `DateTime birthday = DateTime(1996, 12, 12)`. Than you trigger the following:

```
int currentAge = DateTime.now().year - birthday.year;

//Notification setup
AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
AndroidNotificationDetails('your channel id',
        'your channel name', 'your channel description');
IOSNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
    IOSNotificationDetails();
NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
//Iterate for 20 years
for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.schedule(
        0,
        'scheduled title',
        'scheduled body',
        birthday.add(Duration(years: currentAge+i)),
        platformChannelSpecifics);
}
```

Done :)

Ps. Be carefull: DateTime contains also Hour, Minute, Seconds and microseconds. So, if you schedule it, do it properly.

Answer (score -1):

Use this package,

[flutter_local_notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

You can use it like this and use some kind of key value storage to check for which date/year it has been set and based on this check you could reset the notification for next year and so on.

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

initialize() async {
// This is how you initialize the local notification package in flutter.
// Please follow the link above to setup iOS and Android specify permission and configuration.

var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');
var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
  onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification,
);
var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
  initializationSettingsAndroid,
  initializationSettingsIOS,
);
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
     initializationSettings,
     onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification,
   );
}

  Future<void> scheduleUserBirthdayNotification({DateTime dob}) async {
   // nScheduledDobId is your notification id should be integer.
   // cancel the previous one before setting for next year.
   await cancelNotification(withId: nScheduledDobId);

   DateTime commingDate = DateTime.now();

   final scheduledNotificationDateTime =
    DateTime(commingDate.year, dob.month, dob.day, 6);

   await scheduleNotification(
     id: nScheduledDobId,
     title: 'Happy Birthday! ',
     scheduledNotificationDateTime: scheduledNotificationDateTime,
     body:
      "We hope your special day will bring you lots of happiness, love, and fun.",
   );

   await KeyValueStorage().setDobNotificationDate(
     scheduledNotificationDateTime,
   );
}
```

Comment: Ok,but how to add scheduled date and time to it , if my birthday is on 13/04/2000 then in scheduling a notification what should i pass to **var scheduledNotificationDateTime**,that is the main query i am having

Comment: Please check the code that I have attached, hope it will help dissipate the downvote.